# Using Powershell to Change Assignee and Add Comment to Issue via JIRA REST API

Tags: api, rest, powershell, curl, jira

For something so seemingly simple I'm having no luck updating JIRA issues via the REST API.

Has anyone been able to update JIRA issues using Powershell?  I've pretty well exhausted all the options on stackoverflow and atlassian's website.

No scripts for curl, invoke-restmethod or invoke-webrequest have done anything but returned errors.

Retrieving info from the issue is not a problem.  Changing it... holy cow.

I'd be immensely grateful if someone could help me find a way to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `Invoke-RestMethod`. What command are you using and what is the error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Raf. After converting my credentials into b64 I define the specific ticket: $uri="https://jira01.mycompany.com:xxxx/rest/api/2/issue/ABC-1234"  
    $headers = Get-HttpBasicHeader $Credentials
    Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method get -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"

Comment: ..and what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ConvertTo-Base64($string) {
    $bytes  = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($string);
    $encoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes);
    return $encoded;
}

function Get-HttpBasicHeader([string]$username, [string]$password, $Headers = @{}) {
    $b64 = ConvertTo-Base64 "$($username):$($Password)"
    $Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic $b64"
    $Headers["X-Atlassian-Token"] = "nocheck"
    return $Headers
}

function add_comment([string]$issueKey,[string]$comment) {
    $body = ('{"body": "'+$comment+'"}')
    $comment=(Invoke-RestMethod -uri ($restapiuri +"issue/$issueKey/comment") -Headers $headers -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body).id    
    return $comment
}


$restapiuri = "https://jira.server.com/rest/api/2/"
$headers = Get-HttpBasicHeader "user" "password"

add_comment "MyIssue-1234" "[~test.user] please handle the issue."
```

Comment: Välkommen till StackOverflow. It's great that you would like to contribute. However, it would be much better if you commented your code and explained the relevant parts rather than just pasting some code. This will help the asker as well as any future readers to understand.