# JIRA API via powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jira

I want to execute a transition in JIRA via Jenkins.
The Jira Issue Updater is bugged with the affects version so I tried a curl.

This worked out very well:

```
curl -D- -u user:pw -X POST --data {\"transition\":{\"id\":\"71\"}} -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/ID/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
```

But now I have to run this with powershell on a windows server.

Anyone know a workaround for this usecase or how to do that with an Invoke-WebRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the cmdlets from https://atlassianps.org/ I've had a great deal of success with them.  In fact there is an [Invoke-JiraIssueTransition](https://github.com/AtlassianPS/JiraPS/blob/master/JiraPS/Public/Invoke-JiraIssueTransition.ps1) that looks like it would do what you might need.

Answer (score 0):

found this script: [Using Powershell to Change Assignee and Add Comment to Issue via JIRA REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422577/using-powershell-to-change-assignee-and-add-comment-to-issue-via-jira-rest-api?rq=1)

and modified it a little:

```
    function ConvertTo-Base64($string) {
    $bytes  = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($string);
    $encoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes);
    return $encoded;
}

function Get-HttpBasicHeader([string]$username, [string]$password, $Headers = @{}) {
    $b64 = ConvertTo-Base64 "$($username):$($Password)"
    $Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic $b64"
    $Headers["X-Atlassian-Token"] = "nocheck"
    return $Headers
}

function add_comment([string]$issueKey,[string]$comment) {
    $body = ('{"body": "'+$comment+'"}')
    $comment=(Invoke-RestMethod -uri ($restapiuri +"issue/$issueKey/comment") -Headers $headers -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body).id    
    return $comment
}

function transition([string]$issueKey,[string]$transitionid) {
    $body = ('{"transition": "'+$transitionid+'"}')
    $comment=(Invoke-RestMethod -uri ($restapiuri +"issue/$issueKey/transitions?expand=transitions.fields") -Headers $headers -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body).id    
    return $comment
}


$restapiuri = "https://jira.com/rest/api/2/"
$headers = Get-HttpBasicHeader "user" "pw"

add_comment "ticket-id" "comment"
transition "ticket-id" "transitionid"
```